# Getting dynamic values from an array of objects and children by string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm wondering if there is a way to dynamic get children objects dynamically using strings:

Ex: "industry.description"

```
var fields = [{
    id: "1",
    industry: {
      description: "Test Industry1"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    industry: {
      description: "Test Industry2"
    }
  }
  ];

  var field1 = "id";
  var field2 = "industry.description";

  var val1 = fields[0][field1];
  var val2 = fields[0][field2]; // How can I get 'Test Industry1' here?

  console.log(val1);
  console.log(val2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Either do:

```
fields[0]["industry"]["description"];
```

Or separate it into multiple fields (e.g. `[field2][field3]` where `field2 = "industry"` and `field3 = "description"`).

Or, use `reduce` to work with your current string:

```
var val2 = field2.split(".").reduce((o, k) => o[k], fields[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `"industry.description"` key will not work.
What you need is to first get the object under the `"industry"` key and then get the `"description"` from it.
Like this:

```js
fields[0]["industry"]["description"] // "Test Industry1"
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that allows a nested value to be extracted from an object by a dynamically supplied path would be:

```
function getValue(object, path) {

  // Break input path into parts separated by '.' via split
  const parts = path.split(".");

  // Iterate the parts of the path, and reduce that parts array to a single
  // value that we incrementally search for by current key, from a prior
  // nested "value"
  return parts.reduce((value, key) => value ? value[key] : value, object)  
}

console.log(getValue(fields[0], "industry.description")); // Test Industry1
```

The nice thing about this is that it's simple and doesn't require another library to be added to your project. Here's how it works in context of your code:

```js
function getValue(object, path) {
  
  const parts = path.split(".");
  
  return parts.reduce((value, key) => value ? value[key] : value, object)  
}

var fields = [{
    id: "1",
    industry: {
      description: "Test Industry1"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    industry: {
      description: "Test Industry2"
    }
  }
];

var field1 = "id";
var field2 = "industry.description";

console.log(getValue(fields[0], field1))
console.log(getValue(fields[0], field2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fields = [{
    id: "1",
    industry: {
      description: "Test Industry1"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    industry: {
      description: "Test Industry2"
    }
  }
  ];

  var field1 = "id";
  var field2 = "industry";
  var subField2 = "description"

  var val1 = fields[0][field1];
  var val2 = fields[0][field2][subField2]; // How can I get 'Test Industry1' here?

  console.log(val1);
  console.log(val2);
```